# How to randomly select and click a link from a group of links in a webpage using selenium IDE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selenium

I am new to selenium IDE.
After searching for hours, I can't find the way to do what i want.
What I need to do is quite simple.
I have an html page with a lot of bookmarks. I can work with it online or offline.
so I need the script to pick randomly a link from the group of links. then click that link.
What's the easier way to do that?

note: Using firefox and selenium IDE 2.4.0

thanks.

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to achieve ? what have you tried so far ? Where is problem ? seems non constructive question

Comment: I am not sure what you are using with Selenium, but I was using it for c# .net and client side testing.  We use to take all of the items "links", and insert them into a List<string>. Then iterate through using a random number as an index, to choose what link to click. Return the random index item to the selenium function call.

Comment: @Abhijeet Kasurde. sure. there are comments that are non constructive. cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess would be to use the `addScript` command and delegate your task to JavaScript.  I have high doubts that Selenium IDE alone will solve your problem.

Here is some pseudo-code

Target:

Command: addScript

Value:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var randNum = Math.rand(0, links.length());
links[randNum].click()
```